# Laravel 9 - specular model relations not working

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent-relationship

i can't figure out why my eloquent relationship is not working.
I have the grid and details tables related (es. grid.id = details.order_id). This works for first 2 tables but not for other 2 that are almost a copy of the first.

Working relationship code :

OrderGrid model:

```
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'orders_grid';

protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
     // more data
];

public function order_detail()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\OrderDetail');
}
```

OrderDetail model:

```
    use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'orders_detail';

protected $fillable = [
    'order_id',
    // more data
];

public function order_grid()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\OrderGrid', 'order_id', 'id');
}
```

In controller

```
$data_details = OrderDetail::where('order_id', $id)->get();
```

in view

```
$data_details->first()->order_grid->id
// so i can get the ID from the related table
```

[image]

**Now i have two more very similar models which relations are not working:**

OrderGrid model 2

```
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'orders_grid_jde';

protected $fillable = [
    'total_order',
    // more data
];

public function detail_jde()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\OrderDetailJde');
}
```

OrderDetail model 2 :

```
    use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'orders_detail_jde';

protected $fillable = [
    'order_jde_id',
];

public function grid_jde()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\OrderGridJde', 'order_jde_id', 'id');
}
```

In controller:

```
$data_details = OrderDetailJde::where('order_jde_id', $id)->get();
```

In view:

```
$data_details->first()->order_jde_id->id
```

This is not working, if i dump($data_details->first()) **relations** is empty array, not as in the screen shown before

Another weird behaviour on working relation: if i dump $data_details->first() in the controller i don't see the relation, but if i do it in view it shows as in the screen.

Sorry for the long post, tried to be understandble as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Controller call the relation like this:

```
$data_details = OrderDetailJde::where('order_jde_id', $id)->with("grid_jde")->get();
```

In view:
$data_details->first()

It will give all the detils.

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

In the view where you have the error, you are accessing the directly to the field named `order_jde_id` instead of the relationship `grid_jde`.

**Tips:**

You should eager load the relationships if you are planning to use these in the view.

```php
$books = Book::with('author')->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading